# Split a Column >> Get Unique Values >> Add Unique Values back as Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am learning python and have taken a dataset from Kaggle to further understand data exploration and visualization in python.

I have "cuisine" column in the below format from a dataframe:

```py
North Indian, Mughlai, Chinese
Chinese, North Indian, Thai
Cafe, Mexican, Italian
South Indian, North Indian
North Indian, Rajasthani
North Indian
North Indian, South Indian, Andhra, Chinese
```

I want to split this column on comma and fetch unique values from this column. Those unique values I want to add back to the original data frame as new columns.

Based on other posts, I have tried the following:

1) Covert to List and set and flatten out to get unique values

Type function returns Series for the column. Converting it to list and then to set, throws an error

```py
type(fl1.cuisines)
pandas.core.series.Series

cuisines_type = fl1['cuisines'].tolist()
type(cuisines_type)
list

cuisines_type
#this returns list of cuisines

cuisines_set = set([ a for b in cuisines_type for a in b])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

2) Convert it to array and to list

```py
cs = pd.unique(fl1['cuisines'].str.split(',',expand=True).stack())

type(cs)
Out[141]: numpy.ndarray

cs.tolist()
```

This returns list. But i am unable to strip spaces that have been added to some of the elements.

Expected Output is unique list of cuisines and adding it back as columns:

North Indian | Mughlai | Chinese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and if possible duplicates remove them by `max` per columns - output is always `0` or `1` of `sum` for count values:

```
df = fl1.cuisines.str.get_dummies(', ').max(level=0, axis=1)
#if need count values
#df = fl1.cuisines.str.get_dummies(', ').sum(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
   Andhra  Cafe  Chinese  Italian  Mexican  Mughlai  North Indian  Rajasthani  \
0       0     0        1        0        0        1             1           0   
1       0     0        1        0        0        0             1           0   
2       0     1        0        1        1        0             0           0   
3       0     0        0        0        0        0             1           0   
4       0     0        0        0        0        0             1           1   
5       0     0        0        0        0        0             1           0   
6       1     0        1        0        0        0             1           0   

   South Indian  Thai  
0             0     0  
1             0     1  
2             0     0  
3             1     0  
4             0     0  
5             0     0  
6             1     0
```

Similar is possible use your solution with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(fl1['cuisines'].str.split(', ',expand=True).stack()).max(level=0)
```

Comment: This works! I just realized this data would be too sparse to be useful. I will have to club them further. But this solution worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to split this column on comma and fetch unique values from this
>   column. Those unique values I want to add back to the original data
>   frame as new columns

```
a = list(set([i.strip() for i in ','.join(df['cuisine']).split(',')]))
```

**Output**

```
['Thai',
 'Mughlai',
 'Mexican',
 'Rajasthani',
 'Andhra',
 'Chinese',
 'North Indian',
 'Cafe',
 'Italian',
 'South Indian']
```

use `pd.assign` to add these columns back to the original df

```
df.assign(**{i:0 for i in a})
```

Comment: thanks! this worked. There was a NaN value which threw the TypeError. Once I removed NA's, this gave me the list.

Answer (score -1):

Save your fie as csv then use pandas `.read_csv()` method to load it. Then do your parsing per column placing each column in their respective lists then taking the unique values per list.

Initialize a new DataFrame with values from these new lists with now unique entries.

```
df = pd.read_csv('cuisine.csv')
column_1_lst = list(set(df.iloc[:,0].values.tolist()))
.                                                        # period here means up to, like (1, 2,....,n) notation
.
column_n_lst = list(set(df.iloc[:,n].values.tolist()))

new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
new_dataframe['Column_1_unique'] = column_1_lst
.
.
new_dataframe['Column_n_unique'] = column_n_lst
```

Note: just make sure all of your list are of the same length for this to work.

Hope this helps :))